# Material design-inish hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

So basically i have been trying to make this for a looong time and havent found any tutorial regarding it...
I want to make the material design hover where the other color start from the click location and then expands to the whole div

Something like this

https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsLTMzRGZocW50aHc/animation_responsive_userInput_surfacereaction_004.webm

Have been trying something with

```
css box-shadow
```

But no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://materializecss.com/buttons.html

Try those buttons. Just what you're looking for.

They have very beautiful and efficent form handling elements too btw.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

You can have an idea with what you want using Bootstrap Material

[Bootstrap Material Demo](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)
[Original Repository](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design)

Checkout the demos, it may have what you want and do by yourself

Comment: I see it, but i cant find it in the css hah